# Insert multiple rows in SQL as sqlparameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I got 1000 rows in my data-table `dt` and I want to insert all this data to my sql table in one shot.I know how to do this with a for loop..but I wonder is there any other better way to do this all rows to datatbase in single shot.
My current code to insert this data is like this

```
 DataTable dt = result.Tables[0];


        SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text,
                                  "INSERT INTO tbl_Projects (Project,Owner,Consultant ,Contractor,Value ,Level1,Level2 ,Status  ,Country ,CreatedDate  ,CreatedByID ,CreatedByName) VALUES (@Project,@Owner,@Consultant ,@Contractor,@Value ,@Level1,@Level2 ,@Status  ,@Country ,@CreatedDate  ,@CreatedByID ,@CreatedByName)",
                                  new SqlParameter("@Project",dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@Owner", dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@Consultant", dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@Contractor", dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[3]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@Value", dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[4]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@Level1", dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@Level2", dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[6]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@Status", dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[7]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@Country", dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[8]),
                                  new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", System.DateTime.Now),
                                  new SqlParameter("@CreatedByID", ""),
                                  new SqlParameter("@CreatedByName", ""));
```

Can any one give me a hand on this..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by leveraging the `SqlBulkCopy` class. In short, get a `SqlConnection` created and opened and then use this code to copy that in bulk from the `DataTable` to the server.

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_Projects";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a table type parameter and pass an entire dataset from C# to the SQL Server.

See this question: [INSERT using LIST into Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487299/insert-using-list-into-stored-procedure/17487572#comment25416816_17487572)

Answer (score 0):

With C# using `SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con)`

You can insert 10 rows at a time

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("a");
        dt.Columns.Add("b");
        dt.Columns.Add("c");
        dt.Columns.Add("d");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["a"] = 1;
            dr["b"] = 2;
            dr["c"] = "Charan";
            dr["d"] = 4;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String");
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            con.Open();
            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "Sample";
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
```