# Using a comma separated varchar for a IN clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've a list of userId as `DECLARE @userId AS VARCHAR = '1,4,65,12'` that I'd like to use in a IN clause. The result should be like `WHERE Id IN (1,4,65,12)`.

I've tried the following code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUser](@userId VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN(
    SELECT *
    FROM UserTable
    WHERE Id IN (@userId))
```

but it works only for first int value. In this example it works only for 1.

Any idea?

Comment: Your comma separated value is being converted to a single integer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse comma-separated string to make IN List of strings in the Where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: I've already answered this in another question, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160456/sql-server-procedure-declare-a-list/21160840#21160840 to see if this is acceptable to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `IN` clause like that. It compiles to a **single** string in your `IN` clause. But an `IN` clause needs **seperate** values.

```
WHERE id in (@userId)
```

compiles to

```
WHERE id in ('1,4,65,12')
```

but it should be

```
WHERE id in (1,4,65,12)
```

If you really need the query to be dynamic then you can use

```
exec('SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE Id IN (' + @userId + ')')
```

And you need to give your input parameter a length like

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUser](@userId VARCHAR(1000))
```

Comment: Thanks for replay! I've tried, but `exec('SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE Id IN (' + @userId + ')')` return the same as `WHERE Id IN (@userId))`.

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to give your parameter a length: `(@userId VARCHAR(1000))` Otherwise it is just a single character

Answer (score 0):

I've found this question wich is the same:
[Parse comma-separated string to make IN List of strings in the Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause).

I'm going to try this solution.